# How to use Aggregation correctly

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I want to count the quantity of bought products in all orders for a special product but only get 3 back as the result in an appscript. Doesnt matter which product I use.
That is the codesnippet I am using:

```
{% set criteria = {
    'associations': {
        'lineItems': {
            'productId': page.product.id
        }
    },
    'aggregations': [{
        "name": "count-lineItems-quantity",
        "type": "count",
        "field": "order.lineItems.quantity"
    }]
}
%}

{% set orders = services.repository.search('order', criteria) %}
{% do debug.dump(orders.getAggregations.get('count-lineItems-quantity')) %}
```

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction and can show me what I am doing wrong.

Cheers,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably currently are only getting the count of unique line items, not the sum of quantities for each line item.

First, I would use the `order_line_item` repository, unless you need order specific data. I assume you're trying to filter the results by `page.product.id`? Then I would use a filter aggregation to only get line items belonging to a specific product. Then you could have a nested aggregation to sum all the `quantity` fields of occurrences of line items with that `referencedId`.

```json
{
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "name": "my-filter",
            "type": "filter",
            "filter": [
                { 
                    "type": "equals", 
                    "field": "referencedId", 
                    "value": "7594ed63b27345d39f61c82f0b4d4e52" // page.product.id
                }
            ],
            "aggregation": {
                "name": "total-quantity",
                "type": "sum", 
                "field": "quantity"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want the sums for all products, you could have a nested terms aggregation so you get buckets of `quantity` sums per `referencedId`

```json
{
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "name": "my-filter",
            "type": "filter",
            "filter": [
                { 
                    "type": "equals", 
                    "field": "type", 
                    "value": "product"
                }
            ],
            "aggregation": {  
                "name": "per-line-item",
                "type": "terms",
                "field": "referencedId",
                "aggregation": {
                    "name": "total-quantity",
                    "type": "sum", 
                    "field": "quantity"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, youre right, I wanted to filter the result by the productId.

Honestly, I think I couldn't come up with the solution myself, because in my opinion the API Documentation is lacking of some good standard examples.

Thank you very much. Its working like a charm now.